# Redirect to a page for only logged in user

Tags: php

On my website, there are 2 custom pages that are `/login` and `/register`. If logged in user access the pages. I want to redirect them to `/account` page. But not sure if my PHP code is safe to use. The code is working. Please help.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'login_redirect' );
function login_redirect() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        if ( is_page( 'login' ) ) {
            wp_redirect ( site_url( '/account' ) ); exit;
        }
        if ( is_page( 'register' ) ) {
            wp_redirect( site_url( '/account' ) ); exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can merge two condition into a single one.  So your code will be    if(is_page('login') || is_page('register') ) {  your redirect code goes here }

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, if the code works then I'm not sure what the problem is, can you clarify?

Comment: @PradiptaSarkar Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @TomJNowell I'm new in write php code, so is worry about the security of my code skill. I am asking this question to make sure my code above is secure enough to put in my website. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I don't see any security holes here, remember that you need to be able to mark an answer as factually correct, and canonically correct, for all people with this specific question, not just what most reassured you, this isn't a discussion forum so your question need to be clearly stated and specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make more readable, like. Small notes at the code. As a hint, the template tag [is_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) supports an array of values - `is_page( [ 'login', 'register' ] )`.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'login_redirect' );
function login_redirect() {
    // If user is NOT logged in, doing nothing.
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return;
    }
    // This OR (||) this. is_page supports an array of different values.
    if ( is_page( [ 'login', 'register' ] ) ) {
        wp_redirect ( site_url( '/account' ) );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: `add_action( 'template_redirect', 'login_redirect' );
function login_redirect() {
    // If user is NOT logged in, doing nothing.
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return;
    }
    // This OR (||) this. is_page supports an array of different values.
    if ( is_page('login') ) {
            wp_redirect ( site_url( '/pageA' ) );
            exit;
    }
    if ( is_page('register') ) {
            wp_redirect ( site_url( '/pageB' ) );
            exit;
    }
}`

Is this code correct if I want to separate them?

Comment: Yes, but doing the same steps in separate code lines.

Comment: Thank you so much :)